# webservise asp.net mvc2 response

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I've been racking my brain for a couple of days now on how to approach a new requirement.

I have two websites. The first one lets the user fill out an application. The second website is an internal website use to manage the users applications. I need to develop a "web service" that sends the application data from website 1 to website 2. I have never done a web service before and I'm a bit confused on where to start. I've been reading various examples online but they all seem to be just a starting point for building a webservice... no specific examples.

So for posting the data website 1, what would my controller method look like? What would and example of that look like? Is there some form of redirect in the method that points to website 2?

Thanks ahead of time for your assistance. :)